# 1080 HD video display - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, graphics-card, mp4, 1080p

I am running Windows 7 in my Dell Studio 1555 Laptop. I have ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4570 graphics card inside. When I try to watch a video, I can see only some disturbed texture (dark pink grains spread the whole window). I can hear the audio and no prob with that. The I can see the video frames peeking sometimes but is pretty slower.

I have DirectX (directx_Jun2010_redist) and Win7 codecs installed.

Here are some screenshots;

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

The video details are;

```
Name: video.mp4
Frame width: 1920
Frame height: 1080
Frame rate: 29 fps
data Rate: 7958 kbps
Total bitrate: 8052 kbps
```

Just comment if you want more info.

Comment: does this happen only with this one specific video? are your graphic card drivers up to date?

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch this happens with one specific video only in my collection

Comment: my drivers are up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try VideoLAN, as it has all the codecs built in. If it looks OK, then, you are missing the right codec from Windows. If it doesn't look OK, try to upgrade you video drivers. If still it doesn't look OK, perhaps the video is corrupted, and this might be fix with re-encoding software.

Video codecs which might help you see the movie right on Windows MediaPlayer: [xVid](http://www.xvid.org/Downloads.15.0.html), [libav](http://libav.org/download.html)

Comment: I tried VideoLan, but same there `:(`. I can smoothly see video in the `Preview Pane` and is running smoothly. So I am sure that the video is not corrupted and no prob with codecs

Comment: Then try upgrading you video card drivers.

Comment: I tried windows update and said its up to date.

Comment: Get the drivers from AMD site: http://support.amd.com/us/psearch/Pages/psearch.aspx?type=2.4.2&product=2.4.2.3.31&contentType=GPU+Download+Detail&ostype=Select+an+Operating+System+(OS)+type&keywords=&items=20

Comment: The preview pane uses the inbox software decoder. It looks like the drivers for hardware acceleration for the video is corrupted or broken. Try turning off GPU acceleration in VLC

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a more recent catalyst, or alternatively a HCL driver [from Microsoft update catalogs](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/).